# How can I get all the values of from a nested xml?

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, xpath-2.0, wso2-esb

I am getting a response like following where I am getting multiple contract inside contracts. There could be 4 or 3 or 5 contract in a response. I want to get the values of all the ContractStartDate in each contract.

```
<Contracts xmlns="http://www.ggmd.nl/data/service/kpicontract">
   <Contract>
      <ContractStartDate>2015-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate>
      <ContractEndDate>2015-01-10+01:00</ContractEndDate>
      <ContractSubject>02 - 0H304</ContractSubject>
   </Contract>
  <Contract>
      <ContractStartDate>2017-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate>
      <ContractEndDate>2017-01-10+01:00</ContractEndDate>
      <ContractSubject>02 - 0H304</ContractSubject>
   </Contract>
 <Contract>
      <ContractStartDate>2017-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate>
      <ContractEndDate>2017-01-10+01:00</ContractEndDate>
      <ContractSubject>02 - 0H304</ContractSubject>
   </Contract>
</Contracts>
```

**EDIT**
I want out like following:

```
<Dates>
<ContractStartDate>2015-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate>
<ContractStartDate>2017-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate>
<ContractStartDate>2017-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate>
</Dates
```

How can I get all the values of every **ContractStartDate** in **wso2 esb** via using xpath or xslt or script any possible solution?

Comment: what is the output format you need?

Comment: I need xml like <dates><ContractStartDate>2015-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate><ContractStartDate>2017-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate><ContractStartDate>2017-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate>
</dates>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not specified your expected output I will provide you with an `XPATH` solution to fetch the `<ContractStartDate>` nodes from your file:

**Input:**

```
more contracts.xml
<Contracts xmlns="http://www.ggmd.nl/data/service/kpicontract">
   <Contract>
      <ContractStartDate>2015-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate>
      <ContractEndDate>2015-01-10+01:00</ContractEndDate>
      <ContractSubject>02 - 0H304</ContractSubject>
   </Contract>
  <Contract>
      <ContractStartDate>2017-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate>
      <ContractEndDate>2017-01-10+01:00</ContractEndDate>
      <ContractSubject>02 - 0H304</ContractSubject>
   </Contract>
 <Contract>
      <ContractStartDate>2017-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate>
      <ContractEndDate>2017-01-10+01:00</ContractEndDate>
      <ContractSubject>02 - 0H304</ContractSubject>
   </Contract>
</Contracts>
```

**XPATH1:** -> access to all `ContractStartDate` nodes in the XML DOM tree

```
/*[local-name()='Contracts']/*[local-name()='Contract']/*[local-name()='ContractStartDate']
```

**OUTPUT1:**

```
<ContractStartDate>2015-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate><ContractStartDate>2017-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate><ContractStartDate>2017-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate>
```

**XPATH2:** -> access to all `ContractStartDate` nodes text field in the XML DOM tree

```
/*[local-name()='Contracts']/*[local-name()='Contract']/*[local-name()='ContractStartDate']/text()
```

**OUTPUT2:**

```
2015-01-01+01:002017-01-01+01:002017-01-01+01:00
```

after if you need to format the output as you want you can use this specific `XPATH` in your `XSLT` stylesheet

If you want to reach your defined output then you need to use the following `XSLT`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect" extension-element-prefixes="redirect" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="xalan">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
        <dates>
        <xsl:for-each select="/*[local-name()='Contracts']/*[local-name()='Contract']/*[local-name()='ContractStartDate']">
                <ContractStartDate>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </ContractStartDate>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </dates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On your input it produces:

```
$xsltproc contracts.xslt contracts.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dates>
  <ContractStartDate>2015-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate>
  <ContractStartDate>2017-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate>
  <ContractStartDate>2017-01-01+01:00</ContractStartDate>
</dates>
```

Comment: Why should we not suggest simple XPATH: //Contracts/Contract/ContractStartDate

Comment: @Amrendra Kumar this will only return first ContractEndDate not all

Comment: @Allan also my Contracts xml can return multiple contracts its not always 3 it could be more than 3 or less than , depending on the response

Comment: @Aleena: I have implemented what you have asked! It should work on any number of contract nodes ;-)

Comment: I am getting this  2015-01-01+01:002015-06-28+02:002015-04-17+02:002016-06-28+02:00 in result of this property                     <property expression="//Contracts/Contract/ContractStartDate" name="ContractId3" scope="default" type="STRING"/>